# Xpath select text and give bullet list html

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

OK I try to do some web scraping, I know how to select part of site, paragraph, class... 
now, is it possible to select text, extract it and put it between HTML.

Example:

```
This is first paragraph.
This is second paragraph.
```

I wanna get it like a bullet point list.

```
<ul>
    <li>This is first paragraph</li>
    <li>This is second paragraph.</li>
</ul>
```

Or in divs

```
<div id="first">This is first paragraph</div> 
<div id="second">This is second paragraph.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a dom element in XPath, but you can do some string manipulation.

E.g. if your XPath expression to select the example are '//p[1]' and '//p[2]', you can create the list like:

```
concat(
"<ul>",
   "<li>", //p[1],  "</li>",
   "<li>", //p[2], "</li>",
"</ul>")
```

(assuming the paragraph text does not contains special characters like < or &)

There is also XQuery, which is like an extension of XPath, where you can just write:

```
<ul>
    <li>{//p[1]}</li>
    <li>{//p[2]}</li>
</ul>
```

to create that html.

Comment: Thanks people for answering, now I know what to do :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the function tokenize and then a xsl:for-each; it should be ok for you.

Have a check to http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string and http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1205